# Getting error in search script [php, mysqli]

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a very simple and basic search script.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
include('config.php');

$search_token =$_POST['search_token'];

$search_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Forname FROM idea WHERE post_des LIKE '%$search_token%'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query))
  {

  $idea_body = $row['post_des'];

  echo $idea_body;
}
```

But when I execute this, I am having the following Warning:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in F:\Server\xampp\htdocs\p\c3\search.php on line 34
```

Any help for this situation?

Comment: what is the table structure?

Comment: echo your query and make sure it is executing properly.

Comment: Be alarm about `$search_token = $_POST['search_token']`. You could SQL-inject yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a problem in your query, try:

```
$search_query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Forname FROM idea WHERE post_des LIKE '%$search_token%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

To debug your query.

Comment: i think this is probably more suitable for comment.

Comment: oh my!! This fixed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is failing and returning a false value.

put this after your mysqli_query() to see whats going on.

```
if (!$search_query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
```

for more information.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php